# How to change alfresco auditable aspects (creator, modifier etc.)

Tags: alfresco

I've been using Alfresco 4.2. I want to copy the file with all auditable properties copied from the original. The problem is, even so I disabled auditable aspect and put my code in separate transaction the properties can't copy. Is it even possible to copy properties (modified, modifier, created, creator). Below my java code:

```
    result = copy(sourceNodeRef, targetParentNodeRef, assocTypeQName, assocQName, copyChildren);

    UserTransaction userTransaction = transactionService.getUserTransaction();
    try {

        userTransaction.begin();
        this.behaviourFilter.disableBehaviour(result, ContentModel.ASPECT_AUDITABLE);
        this.behaviourFilter.disableBehaviour(QName.createQName("cm:auditable"));

        boolean disableAuditable = this.behaviourFilter.isEnabled(result, ContentModel.ASPECT_AUDITABLE);
        boolean disableCmAuditable = this.behaviourFilter.isEnabled(result, QName.createQName("cm:auditable"));

        copyFileMetadata(sourceNodeRef, result);

        userTransaction.commit();

    } catch (NotSupportedException | SystemException | RollbackException | HeuristicMixedException | HeuristicRollbackException e) {
        logger.error("Error in disabling AUDITABLE ASPECT: " + e);
    } finally {

        this.behaviourFilter.enableBehaviour(result, ContentModel.ASPECT_AUDITABLE);
        this.behaviourFilter.enableBehaviour(QName.createQName("cm:auditable"));

    }
```

I expect to properties to be set to those in copyFileMetadata() but the values stay the same.

Comment: It definitely is possible, I can't tell why it's not working though. Don't give up, disabling definitely is possible.

Comment: Are you using *Big Letter* or *Little Letter* service beans, eg `NodeService` or `nodeService` ?

Comment: little letter service e.g. `nodeService.setProperty(destinationNode, ContentModel.PROP_CREATOR, "test");`

Comment: Could you share full code of your class and xml bean config?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution, here's the full code:

```
UserTransaction userTransaction = transactionService.getUserTransaction();
    Map<QName, Serializable> propertiesCopy = nodeService.getProperties(destinationNode);
    try {

        userTransaction.begin();
        boolean disableAuditable = !this.behaviourFilter.isEnabled(destinationNode, ContentModel.ASPECT_AUDITABLE);
        boolean disableCmAuditable = !this.behaviourFilter.isEnabled(destinationNode, QName.createQName("cm:auditable"));

        if (disableAuditable && disableCmAuditable) {

            //copied node props
            String creator = (String) nodeService.getProperty(sourceNodeRef, ContentModel.PROP_CREATOR);
            Date created = (Date) nodeService.getProperty(sourceNodeRef, ContentModel.PROP_CREATED);
            String modifier = (String) nodeService.getProperty(sourceNodeRef, ContentModel.PROP_MODIFIER);
            Date modified = (Date) nodeService.getProperty(sourceNodeRef, ContentModel.PROP_MODIFIED);

            //copy of node props

            Map<QName, Serializable> auditableProps = new HashMap<>();
            auditableProps.put(ContentModel.PROP_CREATOR, creator);
            auditableProps.put(ContentModel.PROP_CREATED, created);
            auditableProps.put(ContentModel.PROP_MODIFIER, modifier);
            auditableProps.put(ContentModel.PROP_MODIFIED, modified);

            internalNodeService.setProperties(destinationNode, auditableProps);
        }

        userTransaction.commit();

    } catch (NotSupportedException | SystemException | RollbackException | HeuristicMixedException | HeuristicRollbackException e) {
        logger.error("Error in disabling AUDITABLE ASPECT: " + e);
    } finally {

        this.behaviourFilter.enableBehaviour(destinationNode, ContentModel.ASPECT_AUDITABLE);
        this.behaviourFilter.enableBehaviour(destinationNode, QName.createQName("cm:auditable"));

        propertiesCopy.remove(ContentModel.PROP_MODIFIED);
        propertiesCopy.remove(ContentModel.PROP_MODIFIER);
        propertiesCopy.remove(ContentModel.PROP_CREATED);
        propertiesCopy.remove(ContentModel.PROP_CREATOR);

        internalNodeService.setProperties(destinationNode, propertiesCopy);

        this.copyAspects(sourceNodeRef, destinationNode);
    }
```

The problem above was I believe giving the wrong targetNode. Here the destinationNode is result of:

```
NodeRef copyRef = this.services.getCopyService().copyAndRenameAndKeepMeta(this.nodeRef, destination.getNodeRef(),
                    ContentModel.ASSOC_CONTAINS, null, false);
            copy = newInstance(copyRef, this.services, this.scope);
```